# What's the difference in ASP.NET MVC of RedirectToRoute and RedirectToAction?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

What's the difference in ASP.NET MVC of `RedirectToRoute` and `RedirectToAction`? It's not clear what the difference is to me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Redirect to route looks up the route table thats defined in global.asax and redirect to action redirects you to a specified controller/action.

that's about it really

Answer (score 5):

**RedirectToRoute** means it redirects to a specific URL which is defined in routing API.(Global.asax)

**RedirectToAction** will return a **http 302 response** to the browser and then browser will make **GET request** to specified action.

Comment: RedirectToRoute also returning 302 response when you will see in inspect element network tab

Answer (score 3):

Ideally I would use `RedirectToRoute` for Action `Links/Images` and `RedirectToAction` in `Controller's Action` to redirect to another `Controller's Action`.